# How can I stop a function mutate from executing in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to stop this mutate function from executing. ater I call mutate() in List.js when I check the network in my browser I can see that the mutate always executing. I need this to execute once.
This is my List.js which I output the data.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import ListItem from './ListItem'
import FetchData from './FetchData';

    function List() {
      const {
        data,
        loading,
        mutate,
      } = FetchData();
    
      //this needs to stop using interval how?
      mutate();
    
      return (
        <ul>
          {loading && <div>Loading</div>}
          {!loading && (
            <>
              {data.map(item => (<ListItem key={item.id} id={item.id} name={item.name} complete={item.complete} />))}
            </>
          )}
        </ul>
      )
    }
    
    export default List
```

And this is the FetchData.js where the mutate came.

```
import { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const FetchData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data: response } = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost/todolistci/backend/index.php/todos/view",
        { crossDomain: true }
      );
      setData(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const mutate = () => fetchData();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return {
    data,
    loading,
    mutate,
  };
};

export default FetchData;
```

I cant stop mutate from executing, I need it to stop using interval how?
This is the image of the app. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe9ys.png)

Comment: Why are you calling mutate anyways? You have a `useEffect` call that already calls `fetchData`....

Comment: Thank you for replying, This post is the continuation of this, please visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75096687/how-to-refresh-the-list-of-items-after-submitting-a-form-reactjs

Comment: Don't call `mutate` there then. Call it when you need to update the data.

Comment: My problem now is that mutate always executing.

Comment: Then don't call `mutate` *there*. Remove that call. Only call it when you need to update the data. You don't need to update the data every render.

Comment: I call it in List.js to update the data and view it automatically after submitting the form or creating new todo. I think I just need an interval to stop mutate from executing every sec. it should execute once

Comment: It **already** executes once... because of the initial call in `useEffect`. You don't need to call `mutate` here.

Comment: but how can I update the data in list.js to show it automatically after I submit the form?

Comment: Call `mutate`, but only call `mutate` **after** you submit the form.

Comment: I did this already, it can only update the data of FetchData.js but it cant automatically render the output in List.js

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with this mutate function, but I can explain the issue:

Because mutate() is just declared inside your component instead of in a useEffect, it's going to get called any time the component renders & re-renders.

So what happens here, in order (kinda), is:

1. your component renders with data being empty {};
2. your component has a useEffect() to fetch the data, so that gets fired  when it first renders. Which is good.
3. At the same time, mutate() gets called, which also does the same exact fetch call as in the use effect. Bad.
4. You now have two concurrent API calls being sent off.
5. Some time later, one of the two API calls responds first. Doesn't matter which for our purposes.
6. On that response, we call setData(...) and change the state data value.
7. Because the data changed, the component rerenders. Which is good.
8. Because our component rerenders, the mutate() gets called AGAIN. Oh no. we're now fetching data again, will again setData(...), data state value gets changed, and our component rerenders again.... We're stuck in a loop.

On top of all of that, your component has an extra rerender in there when the 2nd of the two fetchData() calls gets returned. Which doesn't matter because it's all broken anyway.

If you get rid of the mutate(), this works fine? I think?

I have no clue what the purpose of the mutate is, other than to cause ridiculous behavior, so I can't advise on how to solve this. Lol.

Comment: Thank you for replying, this post is the continuation of my old post earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75096687/how-to-refresh-the-list-of-items-after-submitting-a-form-reactjs please visit the post and try to read the comments there. I am really confused, hehe, If I did not call mutate in List.js the render wont update after createing new todo thats why I called it there.